# UICollectionView spacing margins

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a `UICollectionView` which shows photos. I have created the collectionview using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It works good but I would like to have spacing on margins. Is it possible to do that using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or must I implement my own `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Comment: the overwhelming issue is `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`.  Take care!

Answer (score 361, accepted):

You can use the `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` method for your `UICollectionView` or set the `sectionInset` property of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object attached to your `UICollectionView`:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
}
```

or

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[aFlowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

## Updated for **Swift 5**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
       return UIEdgeInsets(top: 25, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    }
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting left and right insets to work when using a vertical flow layout...

Comment: Now overriding the sectionInset method of subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout also has no effect. Setting property described below works.

Comment: NB: remember to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your list of ViewController delegates to use the method `insetForSectionAtIndex`

Comment: How can I set this for specific row instead of section.

Comment: when scroll is horizontal, not working

Answer (score 106):

Setting up insets in Interface Builder like shown in the screenshot below

[image: Setting section insets for UICollectionView]

Will result in something like this:

[image: A collection view cell with section insets]

Comment: Great answer, just wanted to point out that you will also have to play with minimum spacing so that section inset works well.

Answer (score 76):

To add spacing on the **entire** `UICollectionView`:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) collection.collectionViewLayout;
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topMargin, left, bottom, right);
```

To play with the spacing **between** elements of the same row (column if you're scrolling horizontally), and their sizes:

```
flow.itemSize = ...;
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = ...;
```

Comment: This works, but the `collection.collectionViewLayout` needs a cast as in the example by @Pooja:

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) self.collectionViewLayout;`

Comment: Casting in swift `if let flow = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout { flow.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) } `

Answer (score 44):

**Swift 4**

```
    let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
    // If you create collectionView programmatically then just create this flow by UICollectionViewFlowLayout() and init a collectionView by this flow.

    let itemSpacing: CGFloat = 3
    let itemsInOneLine: CGFloat = 3
    flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    //collectionView.frame.width is the same as  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width here.
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - itemSpacing * CGFloat(itemsInOneLine - 1) 
    flow.itemSize = CGSize(width: floor(width/itemsInOneLine), height: width/itemsInOneLine)
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = itemSpacing
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change to `scrollDirction` horizontally:

`flow.scrollDirection = .horizontal`

**NOTE**

If you set items in one lines isn't correctly, check if your collection view has paddings. That is:

`let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - itemSpacing * CGFloat(itemsInOneLine - 1)`

should be the collectionView width.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set color to the spacing?

Comment: @MartínDaniel Just set the ```backgroundColor``` of the ```collectionView```. Or whatever the super view.

Comment: but there is no margins at edges

Comment: @user924 Margins at edges can be set with UIEdgeInsets(top: left: bottom: right: ). If scrolling vertically, set the left/right insets. If scrolling horizontally, set the top and bottom insets.

Answer (score 43):

Just to correct some wrong information in this page:

1- **minimumInteritemSpacing**: *The minimum spacing to use between items in the same row.*

The default value: 10.0.

(For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same row.)

2- **minimumLineSpacing** : *The minimum spacing to use between lines of items in the grid.*

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect spacing between sections, only between items within the same section?

Comment: @Crashalot - are you sure you don't mean minimumLineSpacing? i.e. every line of cells? There's also options for Section Insets if you really are using sections.

Comment: This worked for me doing it via the storyboard interface. I was looking for a solution for horizontal only collection views. Thanks +10

Answer (score 11):

### **Modern Swift, Automatic Layout Calculation**

While this thread already contains a bunch of useful answers, I want to add a **modern Swift version**, based on William Hu's answer. It also improves two things:

- The spacing between different lines will now always match the spacing between items in the same line.
- By setting a minimum width, the
  code automatically calculates the number of items in a row and
  applies that style to the flow layout.

Here's the code:

```
// Create flow layout
let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

// Define layout constants
let itemSpacing: CGFloat = 1
let minimumCellWidth: CGFloat = 120
let collectionViewWidth = collectionView!.bounds.size.width

// Calculate other required constants
let itemsInOneLine = CGFloat(Int((collectionViewWidth - CGFloat(Int(collectionViewWidth / minimumCellWidth) - 1) * itemSpacing) / minimumCellWidth))
let width = collectionViewWidth - itemSpacing * (itemsInOneLine - 1)
let cellWidth = floor(width / itemsInOneLine)
let realItemSpacing = itemSpacing + (width / itemsInOneLine - cellWidth) * itemsInOneLine / max(1, itemsInOneLine - 1)

// Apply values
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
flow.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = realItemSpacing
flow.minimumLineSpacing = realItemSpacing

// Apply flow layout
collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(flow, animated: false)
```

Comment: If `itemsInOneLine` is 1 then this will result in a NaN due to dividing by zero here: `itemsInOneLine / (itemsInOneLine - 1)`

Comment: @TylerJames Thanks! I adjusted the code to fix the issue ;)

Answer (score 8):

use `setMinimumLineSpacing:` and `setMinimumInteritemSpacing:` on the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`-Object.

Comment: No it doesnt work, as expected. setMinimumLineSpacing is : The minimum spacing to use between items in the same row. And setMinimumInteritemSpacing is : The minimum spacing to use between lines of items in the grid. My question is about margins not space between elements. eg. Left and top spacing of first element.

Comment: assuming a vertical srollDirection you can use contentInset for top and bottom spacing of the first and last row. Also you could add your margins in your Cells.

Answer (score 8):

Using `collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset` or `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` are correct.

However, if your collectionView has multiple sections and you want to add margin to the whole collectionView, I recommend to use the scrollView contentInset :

```
UIEdgeInsets collectionViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0);
self.collectionView.contentInset = collectionViewInsets;
self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewInsets.top, 0, collectionViewInsets.bottom, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

To put space between `CollectionItem`s use this

**write this two Line in viewdidload**

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(<CGFloat top>, <CGFloat left>, <CGFloat bottom>, <CGFloat right>)
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `insetForSectionAt` property of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object attached to your `UICollectionView`

**Make sure to add this protocol**

```
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

**Swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets (top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right)
    }
```

**Objective - C**

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Objective-C**

```
CGFloat spacing = 5;
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)_habbitCollectionV.collectionViewLayout;
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, spacing, 0, spacing);
CGFloat itemsPerRow = 2;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat oneMore = itemsPerRow + 1;
CGFloat width = screenRect.size.width - spacing * oneMore;
CGFloat height = width / itemsPerRow;

flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(floor(height), height);
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = spacing;
```

All you have to do is change the itemsPerRow value and it will update the number of items per row accordingly.  Furthermore, you can change the spacing value if you want more or less general spacing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice...it's Work Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

For adding margins to specified cells, you can use this custom flow layout.
https://github.com/voyages-sncf-technologies/VSCollectionViewCellInsetFlowLayout/

```
extension ViewController : VSCollectionViewDelegateCellInsetFlowLayout 
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        }
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 and autoLayout, you can use **sectionInset** like this:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (view.frame.width-40)/2, height: (view.frame.width40)/2) // item size
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) // here you can add space to 4 side of item
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout) // set layout to item
        collectionView?.register(ProductCategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier) // registerCell
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white // background color of UICollectionView
        view.addSubview(collectionView!) // add UICollectionView to view
```

Answer (score -1):

To add 10px separation between each section just write this

```
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,10,0);
```

Comment: when using UICollectionReusableView of kind UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, your solution won't work

Answer (score -1):

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {       
         return UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 10, 5, 10);    
   }
```