# Set offset or initial position for a cell in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add some space before the first cell in a collection view, something like an offset, my collection view has a horizontal scroll position.

Here is my current collection view:

[image: current]

It has a leading constraint of 35, what I want is the cell to start at an "x" position of 35 but with the ability to scroll full width like in this:

[image: desired]

Is there a way to create that initial offset in a collection view using Swift 3?

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r

Answer (score 11):

You could just set **Section Insets** for *Collection View Flow Layout* without code.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5 / Xcode 11**

Thanks **Alexander Spirichev**.

Based on his answer, you can also **set** the **left inset** to **35 points** programmatically:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0)

collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set space before the initial cell in collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) as follow:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1) {
  // Set value according to user requirements
  cell.frame.origin.y = 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set contentInset

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
}
```

you can see in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970950/uicollectionview-spacing-margins)

Comment: I only want the space before the initial cell not for all

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but I came across a couple solutions

The right way (scroll to first cell):

https://coderwall.com/p/e-ajeq/uicollectionview-set-initial-contentoffset

Simple hacky way:
I add in a transparent "spacer" cell to the first item to offset the rest of the cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        //spacer
        return CGSize(width:6, height:50)
    }
    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the cells in that section to have the padding, then use `sectionInset` from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as suggested in the other answers.
But from what I can guess you're probably fine with instead setting `contentInsets` on the collection view itself (inherited from `UIScrollView`)