# Why am i getting extra space after end of the last cell on a Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift

In my collection view I am getting extra space at the end of the last cell.
The space also increases if the number of cells increases.
The background color of collection view is yellow. How can I stop this extra space?
In Second Image the Height And Width of the Cell Is half of that of the Collection View.

[image: ImageofSimulato[Image Second]r][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTCoi.png)

This is my code for ViewController.swift File

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pagecontrol: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var VarBtnGet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var MainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SubScrollView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnsetuplayout()
        pagecontrolsetup()
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate  = self
        collectionviewsetup()




    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? .green : .red

        return cell

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionview.frame.width, height: collectionview.frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 0
    }
    func btnsetuplayout()
    {
        VarBtnGet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        VarBtnGet.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:SubScrollView.bottomAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true
               VarBtnGet.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubScrollView.leftAnchor ,constant: 0
               ).isActive = true
               VarBtnGet.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubScrollView.rightAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true

    }
    func pagecontrolsetup()
    {
        pagecontrol.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pagecontrol.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  VarBtnGet.topAnchor,constant: -100  ).isActive = true
        pagecontrol.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  SubScrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pagecontrol.backgroundColor = .brown


    }
    func collectionviewsetup()
    {

        collectionview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionview.isPagingEnabled = true
     //   collectionview.frame =  CGRect.zero
        if let layout = collectionview.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }

        collectionview.backgroundColor = .yellow
        collectionview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo : SubScrollView.topAnchor ,constant: 5 ).isActive = true

          collectionview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubScrollView.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        collectionview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:SubScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

         //collectionview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubScrollView.leftAnchor,constant: 5) .isActive=true
         //collectionview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubScrollView.rightAnchor,constant: -5) .isActive=true
    }


    @IBAction func ButtonGet(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970950/uicollectionview-spacing-margins

Comment: Hey Piyush! Did you find the solution? Actually I am also facing the same.

Comment: Hi Piyush, did you find any solutions to this problem? I have the same problem but i can't figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the minimum spacing between items and set it to `0` with [minimumInteritemSpacing](http://://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617706-minimuminteritemspacing)?   It defaults to `10.0` so might explain what you're seeing.  I see you set the line spacing to `0` so that's good.

Comment: yes i have set it to 0 but i am getting  space at the end of  the last  cell not in between them

Comment: Have you set the `sectionInset` possibly to non-zero?  Did you add section headers or footers with `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`?

Answer (score 3):

i know that is an old post but i had the same issue and i found a solution. I hope that this answer could be helpful for someone. In my case the i solved my problem changing the collection view property **Estimated size** from **Automatic** to **None**. In my case this solved the problem.

[image]

Set Estimate Size to none using storyboard in order to make it work properly. If you will not set that than below code will not work as expected.

Comment: Note that, incredibly confusingly, when doing this in code, it seems that `yourLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero` is the equivalent.  It seems that CGSizeZero just "means" whatever the hell the "None" popup selection is, on storyboard. Everyone hates this :/

Answer (score 0):

Solution for NS/UICollectionViewLayout. It's caused by the width/height of the group being set as absolute / fractional. Make the scrolling side as estimated.

```
NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1.0), 
                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
```